# 0x80004005 Error when trying to copy file from guest to VM using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, copy, hyper-v

By using the Copy-VMFile command in powershell (Windows 10), I receive the 0x8004005 ( non specified error).

The cammand used is : Copy-VMFile -VMName n1 -FileSource Host -CreateFullPath -SourcePath "C:/Downloads/fichier1.tar.gz" -DestinationPath "/Downloads"

How can I resolve this problem ?

Comment: Any chance `-DestinationPath "/Downloads/"` works?

Comment: This behavior may occur if certain dynamic-link library files (.dll files) are not registered correctly or if there is a firewall between the computer and the Internet that does not allow HTTPS (SSL) connections. See: ["Error: 0x8004005" or "Error: 0x800C0005" error messages when you scan for updates](https://support.microsoft.com/nl-nl/help/843499/error-0x8004005-or-error-0x800c0005-error-messages-when-you-scan-for-u)